# How to navigate to another view controller when search bar is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, search, uisearchbar

I am a bit stuck here. I have a search bar embedded in my navigation bar as the title which I want.

However next I would like to navigate to another view controller containing a UIsearchcontroller in a collection view, and when cancel is tapped the user is brought back to the previous view. (Very similar to Facebook or Instagrams use of the search bar controller)

Is there anyway I can use the search bar as a button to navigate to the next view controller that handles all of the search functions?

This is what I have so far for the search bar.

```swift
    func setUpNavBar() {
       let searchBar = UISearchBar()
       searchBar.sizeToFit()
       searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
       searchBar.placeholder = "Search by username"
       searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
       searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
       navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
       searchBar.isTranslucent = true
       }
```

**Edit**

Just to add on to the answer below, if anyone comes across this and you want to get the effect that treats the search bar as a button use

```
  func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchBarController()), animated: true, completion: nil)
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        return false
    }
```

This way, when you click the search bar, you do not get the effect that shows the search bar active,( if that makes sense). When you tap the search bar, there is no effect, it just takes you to the (real) search view controller then the search bar is active and the keyboard is displayed with a cancel button. I hope that makes sense, if anyone wants an example go to Instagram, FB, or Pinterest and tap on their search bar or search icon and you'll see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `UISearchBarDelegate` in first view controller. And in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method present the second view controller.

```
//ViewController.swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNavBar()
    }
    func setUpNavBar() {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search by username"
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchViewController()), animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
//SearchViewController.swift
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setUpNavBar()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    func setUpNavBar() {
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search by "
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there anyway I can make SearchViewController open with searchController instead? So it opens with the keyboard, and cancel button ready to go? If canceled is clicked it takes user back to previous VC?

Comment: @Clint Yes.t you can use searchController. In `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` delegate method call `self.dismiss` method

Comment: @Clint and use custom delegate to pass the selected value to previous view controlller in `tableViewDidSelect` method

Comment: I am opting to use a collection view rather than a tableView for my search results. What do you mean when you say use a custom delegate?

Comment: @Clint Use [collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)